# Element div not allowed as child of element label in this context

Tags: html

Line 178, Column 1672: Element div not allowed as child of element label in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
… Текст14

При валидации появилась такая ошибка. Красным показывает закрывающую скобку "`<div>`".
Пример кода:

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="c2" value="2">
<label for="c2">
 <div>Текст
    <span>14</span>
 </div>
</label>
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Кстати, ещё на заметку: можно делать вот так `<label><input type="checkbox" /> Текст <span>14</span></label>`

Comment: Спасибо! все получилось

Answer (score 2):

`<label>` является [строчным элементом](http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/blochnaya-verstka/strochnye-elementy) (если объяснять по-простому, предназначен для текста и не имеет конкретной формы), а `<div>` блочным (прямоугольник). Вкладывать блочные элементы внутрь строчных по стандарту запрещено. Их надо поменять местами:

```
<div>
  <label for="c2">Текст
    <span>14</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

(На заметку: точно так же нельзя запихивать div внутрь span, распространённая ошибка.)